# Implementing dropdown menu in phpMyAdmin

Tags: sql, database

I'm learning databases, I have a question:
Is it possible to create a drop down menu in SQL?

for example: Create a drop down menu for Gender, so a user can select either Male or Female?

Many Thanks

Answer (score 4):

If you use [MySQL `ENUM` data types](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/enum.html) as your table column data type, then phpMyAdmin will present the option values to you as a drop-down selector.

**Adding an `ENUM` column:**

[image: Adding column]

**Inserting a row:**

[image: Adding row]